# Bulk insert XML data into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, bcp

Using the table structure below how would I create a bcp bulk insert that would handle the XML data.  It is important that this is run from command line.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
[MyXmlField] [xml] NULL
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you provide some detail about the layout of the input file - particularly where the line-breaks fall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic syntax for using bcp is:

```
bcp <table_name> <direction> <file_name> <options>
```

Where the arguments take the following values:

- **table_name** is the fully qualified
  name of the table. For example, you
  might use inventory.dbo.fruits to
  insert records into the fruits table,
  owned by the database owner, in the
  inventory database.
- **direction** indicates whether you want
  to import (“in” direction) or export
  (“out” direction) data.
- **file_name** is the full path to the
  file. For example, you could import
  the file C:\fruit\inventory.txt.
- **options** allow you to specify
  parameters for the bulk operation.
  For example, you can specify the
  maximum number of errors allowed with
  the –m option. You may also use the
  –x option to specify an XML file
  format. Consult Microsoft’s bcp
  documentation for a full list.

Will need more info to know what switches to use, but it should be somehting like

```
bcp database.dbo.MyTable in "C:\folder\xmlfile.xml" -c -T
```

**-c** Performs the operation using a character data type. 
**-T** Specifies that the bcp utility connects to SQL Server with a trusted connection using integrated security.

Also here is [Microsoft's bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) which should help you with knowing what switches to use.

Answer (score 0):

use -N switch if your file contains unicode characters.

> -N  : Performs the bulk-copy operation using the native (database) data types of the data for noncharacter data, and Unicode characters for character data. This option offers a higher performance alternative to the -w option, and is intended for transferring data from one instance of SQL Server to another using a data file. It does not prompt for each field. Use this option when you are transferring data that contains ANSI extended characters and you want to take advantage of the performance of native mode.